System Program Address (2rbMgYvzAb3xDk6vXrzKkY3VwsmyDZsJTkvB3JJYsRzA) Keeps Selling My SPL Token Without Buying
I'm working with a custom SPL Token on the Solana blockchain, and I noticed that the system program address (2rbMgYvzAb3xDk6vXrzKkY3VwsmyDZsJTkvB3JJYsRzA) keeps selling my token. However, I never see any record of it buying the token in the first place.
I am using the standard Solana web3.js and @solana/spl-token libraries to manage token transfers. I'm not sure how this system address is acquiring the tokens,
and it’s not clear where the tokens are coming from.
Steps Taken:
I reviewed my minting and transfer logic but didn’t find any direct interaction with this system address.
Any suggestions on what might be happening here or how I can debug this further?
Additional Information:
Token minting and transfers are handled by the Token Program (TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA).
Could this be related to account creation or some hidden logic in the System Program?
Thanks for any help!
